# "found him brighter than during our meeting" – unmatched comparison with 'than'

Tags: comparative-constructions

> Contrary to earlier reports I found him brighter than during our meeting.

I read this sentence in a Google Books library of a author Thorpe Edgar, don't know if he is a native speaker or not. Also I couldn't find answer to this question in those pages which were accessible by Google Books preview but I googled for the sentence and found two results. One says replace *brighter than* with *bright*, and the other says it's a *No Error* sentence, but I think it's not an error free sentence as *than* (a comparative) has been used in the sentence but the clause/subject/object with which comparison is to be made is not present. So what should be the correction? Replacing *brighter than* with *bright*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ordinary comparative reduction. In a clausal complement of a comparative, the actual value to which comparison is made is always omitted, and everything except the contrasting element *may* be omitted:

> I found him brighter than [he was <s>*X bright*</s> during our meeting]
>    ↓
>   I found him brighter than [<s>he was *X bright*</s> during our meeting]